# How to prompt user to select file location in VBA to merge files into one workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to prompt the user to select the folder path with FileDialog and integrate it with a routine which imports the desired files to the open workbook.

Below is my code but rather than pre-determining the folderpath I need to prompt the user:

```vb
Sub MergeCsvFilesToWb()

    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim fldr As FileDialog

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select the Folder where the '.csv' files are located."
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
    End With

    FolderPath = fldr.SelectedItems(1)
    Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.csv*")

    Do While Filename <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
            
        For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Next Sheet
            
        Workbooks(Filename).Close
        Filename = Dir()
        
    Loop
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your attempt using `FileDialog`

Comment: @RaymondWu It is now updated

Comment: Debug your code and make sure the variable `msoFileDialogFolderPicker` has a valid value (not zero). VB will not warn you if the variable doesn't exist. Can you explain what unexpected thing happens when you try to do this?

Comment: If you look at `FileDialog` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.filedialog) (and it's [object documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.filedialog)) and its example, you would see that `SelectedItems` property contains a collection of the selected folder/file. Since folder picker only allows you to select 1 folder, try `FolderPath = fldr.SelectedItems(1)`

Comment: File Dialog box will pop up, but once I've selected the folder the files aren't imported to the workbook (with the newly added line). @RaymondWu

Comment: @caseolive Edit your question and include your edited code. Also debug your code line by line and see what is `FolderPath` after you selected the folder. Also note that the folder path returned does not have a slash at the end so you need to change `Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.csv*")` to `Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "\*.csv*")` or `FolderPath = fldr.SelectedItems(1)` to `FolderPath = fldr.SelectedItems(1) & "\"`

Comment: @RaymondWu It is working perfectly! Thank you so much I appreciate the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The File/Folder selected in `FileDialog` can be found in the `SelectedItems` property ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.filedialog.selecteditems))

So to assign the variable `FolderPath` to the selected folder:

```
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select the Folder where the '.csv' files are located."
        .Show
        
        Dim FolderPath As String
        FolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
```

Note that you should handle the event that the user does not select any folder (click `Cancel`) in the dialog so a better version would be:

```
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select the Folder where the '.csv' files are located."
        .Show
        
        Dim FolderPath As String
        If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
            FolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            'Code to handle event that nothing is selected
            'e.g.
            'Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
```

Lastly, the folder path returned does not have a slash at the end so you will need to either:

1. Modify `Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.csv*")` to `Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "\*.csv*")`
2. Modify `FolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)` to `FolderPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"`